# Difficulty understanding this query oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I just want to know the internal execution of this query especially how the values in from subquery are being used

```
SELECT bu, location FROM 
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT bu, hqname, location FROM DOCTOR 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT bu, hqname, location FROM CHEMIST 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT bu, hqname, location FROM STOCKIST
) 
GROUP BY bu, location 
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT hqname) > 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commented SQL

```
  SELECT -- bu and location from doctors, chemists and stockists 
         -- (see inner query)  
         bu, 
         location
    FROM ( -- All doctors, chemists and stockists 
           -- with duplicates removed: 
           -- e.g. if a person is a chemist and a doctor, only one record is preserved
          SELECT DISTINCT bu, 
                          hqname, 
                          location 
                     FROM DOCTOR
           UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT bu, 
                          hqname, 
                          location 
                     FROM CHEMIST
           UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT bu, 
                          hqname, 
                          location 
                     FROM STOCKIST)
GROUP BY -- combining "bu" and "location" (for HAVING)
         bu, 
         location
         -- choose these records only that have more than one hqName
         -- for the same bu and location, e.g. 
         -- hqName bu loc
         --      x  1   2
         --      x  1   2 <-- second hqName ("x") for the same bu and loc (1, 2)
  HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT hqname) > 1;
```

Comment: ' choose these records only that have more than one hqName
         -- for the same bu and location, e.g. 
         -- hqName bu loc'

Answer (score 1):

The subquery returns unique cobinations of `bu, hqname, location`

Then they are grouped and only locations where there are more than one hqname remain.

Answer (score 0):

In below query the result of three tables 'DOCTOR','CHEMIST' and 'STOCKIST' combined to one result (treated as table) using UNION

```
    SELECT DISTINCT bu, hqname, location FROM DOCTOR 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT bu, hqname, location FROM CHEMIST 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT bu, hqname, location FROM STOCKIST
```

Aggregated data is fetched using GROUP BY with count of hqname > 1 for every 
(bu, location ) group as below

```
GROUP BY bu, location 
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT hqname) > 1;
```

and finally you will get unique bu, location from from the result set
simply put as

```
SELECT  bu, location FROM Resultset
GROUP BY bu, location 
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT hqname) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query without using `DISTINCT` which return the same results -

```
SELECT bu, location
FROM (  
    SELECT bu, hqname, location FROM DOCTOR
    UNION
    SELECT bu, hqname, location FROM CHEMIST
    UNION
    SELECT bu, hqname, location FROM STOCKIST
) AS t
GROUP BY bu, location
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT hqname) > 1
```